# : Error: The getter 'ut' isn't defined for the class 'BlocBase<State>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-bloc

I am following this example https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login

with this following dependency

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  flow_builder: ^0.0.9
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3+10
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
  form_inputs:
    path: ../packages/form_inputs
  formz: ^0.4.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  meta: ^1.8.0
```

and then I am running the app it return this following error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
: Error: 'rethrow' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
../…/src/bloc_base.dart:105
Try renaming this to be an identifier that isn't a keyword.
      ut.rethrow;
         ^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'ut' isn't defined for the class 'BlocBase<State>'.
../…/src/bloc_base.dart:105
- 'BlocBase' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' ('../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.1.0/lib/src/bloc.dart').
package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ut'.
      ut.rethrow;
      ^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I tried also with

flutter_bloc : ^ 8.1.0 and 8.0.1 also return the same issue

Anyone have the same issue, and if so what is your suggesstion  ?

Comment: Make sure your FLutter version is compatible with the one mentioned in example

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved by

```
flutter pub cache repair
```